# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar una API de Clima correspondiente a un País en particular en ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una aplicación la cual en primera instancia muestra muestra todos los países, si el filtro coincide con un único País muestra todos los datos de ese país, la cuestión viene aquí, estoy ocupando un API de clima la cual por URL debo enviar el nombre del país o la capital de dicho país de la única coincidencia del buscador cuando solo muestra un único país

**Parte del código con problema**

La parte del código donde presento el problema es el siguiente, aquí hago la solicitud a la API, pero en `Quito` debe ir solo el país que muestra como única coincidencia el filtro de búsqueda, osea debe ser dinámico ese campo por lo que no sé como hacerlo ya que el único lugar donde se renderizaría es en el primer if donde si la longitud del buscador es igual a 1 procede a renderizar toda la información del país y ahi debería ir la información del clima.

```
useEffect(() => {
axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Quito&appid=c97566f1aafdd1d33ea80ef1a1ccfebd`)
     .then(response => {
       const apiResponse = response.data;
       console.log(apiResponse);
       setWeatherInfo(apiResponse);
     }).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
}, []);
```

**Aquí debo renderizar la información del clima del país que muestra como única coincidencia el buscador**

```
  if (findCountry.length === 1) {
    return (
        /*findCountry.map(countryData => <div>
          <p>find countries <input onChange={handleFindCountry}/></p>
          <h1>{countryData.name}</h1>
          <p>capital {countryData.capital}</p>
          <p>population {countryData.population}</p>
          <h2>Languages</h2>
          <ul>
            {countryData.languages.map(languageName => <li key={countryData.alpha2Code}>{languageName.name}</li>)}
          </ul>
          <img height={100} src={countryData.flag} alt={countryData.name}/>
        </div>)*/
        <div>
          <p>find countries <input onChange={handleFindCountry}/></p>
          <h1>{findCountry[0].name}</h1>
          <p>capital {findCountry[0].capital}</p>
          <p>population {findCountry[0].population}</p>
          <h2>Languages</h2>
          <ul>
            {findCountry[0].languages.map(languageName => <li key={languageName.name}>{languageName.name}</li>)}
          </ul>
          <img height={100} src={findCountry[0].flag} alt={findCountry[0].name}/>
          <h2>Weather in {findCountry[0].capital}</h2>
          <strong>temperature: {weatherInfo.weather[0].icon}</strong>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

**Código completo de la aplicación**

[image: Código de la aplicación]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo esta forma de hacerlo:

Primero creamos un nuevo estado llamado `capital` con el valor inicial "Quito".

```
const [capital, setCapital] = useState("Quito");
```

Luego modificamos la función `handleFindCountry` y le agregamos un par de cosas más.

```
const handleFindCountry = (event) => {
    setFindCountries(event.target.value);
    const findCountry = countries.filter((country) =>
      country.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
    );
    if (findCountry.length === 1) {
      setCapital(findCountry[0].capital);
      console.log("setCapital ");
    }
  };
```

Ahí dentro estará la condición de que si es un solo país el encontrado, se setee el estado `capital` justamente con la capital del país.

Después, modificamos el `useEffect()` que traerá los datos del clima de la capital.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // const countryCapital = countries.map(countryCap=>countryCap.capital)
    // console.log(countryCapital);
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${capital}&appid=c97566f1aafdd1d33ea80ef1a1ccfebd`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const apiResponse = response.data;
        console.log(apiResponse);
        setWeatherInfo(apiResponse);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [capital]);
```

De esa forma, mediante el `${capital}`, hacemos que la consulta sea dinámica y con el `[capital]` hacemos que se ejecute por cada vez que se setea el estado.

Ahora se mostrará dinámicamente el clima de cada capital.

Todo el código quedaría así:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [findCountries, setFindCountries] = useState("");
  const [showCountryInfo, setShowCountryInfo] = useState("");
  const [weatherInfo, setWeatherInfo] = useState([]);
  const [capital, setCapital] = useState("Quito");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then((response) => {
      // console.log(response);
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleFindCountry = (event) => {
    setFindCountries(event.target.value);
    const findCountry = countries.filter((country) =>
      country.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
    );
    if (findCountry.length === 1) {
      setCapital(findCountry[0].capital);
      console.log("setCapital ");
    }
  };
  const findCountry = countries.filter((country) =>
    country.name.toLowerCase().includes(findCountries.toLowerCase())
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // const countryCapital = countries.map(countryCap=>countryCap.capital)
    // console.log(countryCapital);
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${capital}&appid=c97566f1aafdd1d33ea80ef1a1ccfebd`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const apiResponse = response.data;
        console.log(apiResponse);
        setWeatherInfo(apiResponse);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [capital]);

  console.log(weatherInfo);

  const showCountryInformation = (event) => {
    // console.log(event.target.value);
    setShowCountryInfo(() => {
      const singleCountryInfo = countries.filter((country) =>
        country.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
      );

      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{singleCountryInfo[0].name}</h1>
          <p>capital {singleCountryInfo[0].capital}</p>
          <p>population {singleCountryInfo[0].population}</p>
          <h2>Languages</h2>
          <ul>
            {singleCountryInfo[0].languages.map((languageName) => (
              <li key={languageName.name}>{languageName.name}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <img
            height={100}
            src={singleCountryInfo[0].flag}
            alt={singleCountryInfo[0].name}
          />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  if (findCountry.length === 1) {
    return (
      /*findCountry.map(countryData => <div>
          <p>find countries <input onChange={handleFindCountry}/></p>
          <h1>{countryData.name}</h1>
          <p>capital {countryData.capital}</p>
          <p>population {countryData.population}</p>
          <h2>Languages</h2>
          <ul>
            {countryData.languages.map(languageName => <li key={countryData.alpha2Code}>{languageName.name}</li>)}
          </ul>
          <img height={100} src={countryData.flag} alt={countryData.name}/>
        </div>)*/
      <div>
        <p>
          find countries <input onChange={handleFindCountry} />
        </p>
        <h1>{findCountry[0].name}</h1>
        <p>capital {findCountry[0].capital}</p>
        <p>population {findCountry[0].population}</p>
        <h2>Languages</h2>
        <ul>
          {findCountry[0].languages.map((languageName) => (
            <li key={languageName.name}>{languageName.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <img height={100} src={findCountry[0].flag} alt={findCountry[0].name} />
        <h2>Weather in {findCountry[0].capital}</h2>
        <strong>temperature: {weatherInfo.weather[0].icon}</strong>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (findCountry.length <= 10 && findCountries.length > 1) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          find countries <input onChange={handleFindCountry} />
        </p>

        {findCountry.length > 10 && findCountries !== "" ? (
          <p>Too many matches, specify another filter</p>
        ) : (
          findCountry.map((country) => (
            <p key={country.name}>
              {country.name}
              <button value={country.name} onClick={showCountryInformation}>
                show
              </button>
            </p>
          ))
        )}

        {showCountryInfo}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        find countries <input onChange={handleFindCountry} />
      </p>

      {findCountry.length > 10 && findCountries !== "" ? (
        <p>Too many matches, specify another filter</p>
      ) : (
        findCountry.map((country) => <p key={country.name}>{country.name}</p>)
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Código de la aplicación]

Pruébalo en el **fork** que hice de tu código.

Comment: Muchas gracias compa, funciona según lo que requería.